# WDataTransferer type not visible

Tags: java

Testing upgrade to JDK 1.8 from 1.6. Seeing error in existing code when referencing the WDataTransferer type. Error indicates the type not visible. The import `sun.awt.windows.*` is present in the class.
Not sure what policy has changed to make this private.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use sun.* packages with JDK 1.8 so fell back to 1.7. Platform independence is the need to drop sun.* references.